# Lpc 43s50FET256 processor and its connections

Tags: microcontroller, ethernet, microprocessor, processor, nxp

ı want to buy a nxp [LPC43S50FET256](http://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/LPC43S50_30_20.pdf) processor and ı made some research but I dont know whether lpc43s50 has already got bridge connections, ı also dont know for example whether ethernet is already connected or not I couldnt understand from the datasheet and there is not enough information about this processor so ı couldnt understand whether this is an  only  processor or are  there some other part which has already connected to processor for example ethernet and some other ports. Exactly what ı mean is whether this is a processor or microprocessor board

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Please run your question though a word processor. Hundreds of words but only one period and no question mark.

Comment: thanks but ı will do this other time .I have already got my answer .Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This device actually has two processor cores and includes many peripherals including an Ethernet MAC. It is *not* a development board it's an IC. By the way, it has no on-chip flash.

Not wanting to be rude, but if you can't glean this from that datasheet, it sounds like a heck of an undertaking for you.

Why do you want to use this chip specifically?

Comment: ı will use this chip to control an interface with I/O  control by connecting an SSR , and other applications but by looking this datasheet ı couln't understand for example  whether ethernet port has already connected or not  as well as lcd

Comment: Otherwise ı will have to add this ports externally

Comment: what ı want to know is  what this package consists of

Comment: ı am an intern at company and ı have responsibiliy about how to connect and use ethernet port to Lpc43s50fet256 processor

Comment: As I said it has an Ethernet MAC. You will need a PHY, but that is normal. You also now say you want LCD interface and this also has that. When you say what the package consists of, are you asking what package type it is or what peripherals? Both are clearly explained in the the datasheet yo linked to.

Comment: yeah ı looked at the datasheet but when ı look at the picture of this processor ı see onlu 256 hole:))

Comment: are lcd or ethernet mac inside of this ? secondly how can ı make bridge connections of this processor because ı need a lot of pin

Comment: They are both peripherals integral to the IC, so yes and therefore you need no "bridge" connections as you call it other than to the PHY and direct to the LCD. Again, not wanting to be rude, but you need to learn to read datasheets.

Comment: ı really appreciate your efforts